# How to use IOServiceOpenAsFileDescriptor?

Tags: c++, macos, usb, iokit

I have a USB device attached. I decided to try to write some code where I open the USB device as a FileDescriptor like on Linux where I can use `ioctl` function on the `fd` to send commands.

I ended up with the following:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef matches = IOServiceMatching(kIOUSBDeviceClassName);
    if (!matches)
    {
        std::cerr<<human_error_string(kIOReturnError)<<"\n";
        return;
    }

    io_iterator_t deviceIterator;
    kern_return_t kr = IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, matches, &deviceIterator);
    if (kr != kIOReturnSuccess)
    {
        std::cerr<<human_error_string(kr)<<"\n";
        return;
    }

    io_service_t service = IO_OBJECT_NULL;
    while((service = IOIteratorNext(deviceIterator)))
    {   
        int32_t fd = IOServiceOpenAsFileDescriptor(service, O_RDWR) //doesn't work! Returns: -1

        IOObjectRelease(service);
    }
    IOObjectRelease(deviceIterator);
```

However, the FD is always -1.. Any ideas why?

Comment: What sort of commands are you planning to send to this file descriptor?

Comment: @pmdj; Read, Write, Control Descriptors, etc.. I already have it all working normally, but I want to know if I can open it as a File Descriptor.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there isn't any kind of file descriptor based API for USB on macOS. You need to go through the `IOUSB` based APIs, or if you want to share as much code as possible between Linux an macOS, you can use libusb which wraps both Apple's IOKit API and Linux's `ioctl` based USB API. I'm not exactly sure what `IOServiceOpenAsFileDescriptor` is intended for, perhaps it's for accessing block devices or serial ports, which have both an IOKit object and a device node file in `/dev/`. General USB devices do not have a node in the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't any kind of file descriptor based API for USB on macOS. You need to go through the IOUSB based APIs. There's some example code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBDeviceInterfaces/USBDevInterfaces.html).

If you want to share as much code as possible between Linux an macOS, you can use [libusb](https://libusb.info/) which wraps both Apple's IOKit API and Linux's ioctl based USB API.

I have to admit I'm not exactly sure what `IOServiceOpenAsFileDescriptor` is intended for. The [source code in IOKitLib](https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOKitUser/IOKitUser-1483.220.15/IOKitLib.c.auto.html) is not terribly enlightening, as it simply connects to an XPC service and the file descriptor is expected in the XPC reply. I assume the service is implemented in a system daemon that isn't open source or documented.

Perhaps `IOServiceOpenAsFileDescriptor` is for accessing block devices or serial ports, which have both an IOKit object and a device node file in `/dev/`. General USB devices do not have a node in the file system.